# shifting a pandas datetime index

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

This is a really stupid question, I am guessing, but anyway, here goes:

I have a dataframe with a datetime index which looks like this:

```
DatetimeIndex(['1995-01-02', '1995-01-03', '1995-01-04', '1995-01-05',
               '1995-01-06', '1995-01-09', '1995-01-10', '1995-01-11',
                '1995-01-12', '1995-01-13'])
```

Not too surprisingly, the `time` field is "00:00:00":

```
bets.index.map(pd.datetime.time)
```

gives:

```
 Index([00:00:00, 00:00:00, 00:00:00, 00:00:00, 00:00:00, 00:00:00, 00:00:00,
       00:00:00, 00:00:00, 00:00:00])
```

I would like to set the time field  to something else (e.g., noon), for **all** the index elements. What is the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you could use `to_timedelta` and pass in the required number of hours:

```
bets.index += pd.to_timedelta('12h')
```

Output:

```
DatetimeIndex(['1995-01-02 12:00:00', '1995-01-03 12:00:00',
               '1995-01-04 12:00:00', '1995-01-05 12:00:00',
               '1995-01-06 12:00:00', '1995-01-09 12:00:00',
               '1995-01-10 12:00:00', '1995-01-11 12:00:00',
               '1995-01-12 12:00:00', '1995-01-13 12:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```